# How to transfer a Magento website from one server to another

Tags: magento, magento2, transfer, vs-web-site-project

do you know how to transfer a Magento website from one server to another?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as a new installation :

Install stack you need eg. Nginx - PHP - Mysql,...
To do so You can take a look at this great instruction.
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-magento-2-on-ubuntu-18-04/

summory:

- git clone
- composer install
- import db
- update `core_config_data` set `value` = 'https://YOURDOMAIN' where `path` IN('web/unsecure/base_url','web/secure/base_url','web/secure/base_url_link');
- Change magento-root-directory in composer.json in case you need it.
- Depends on you are adding pub/media in your repo or not you should transfer media folder
- rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/* && php bin/magento cache:clean &&php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f